# Write a SQL query to find employees who earn the top three salaries for the IT department

Tags: sql, sql-server

Write a SQL query to find employees who earn the top three salaries for the IT department.

My query:

```sql
SELECT TOP(3) WITH TIES 
    d.name AS department, e.name AS employee, e.salary 
FROM 
    employee e, department d
WHERE 
    e.departmentid = d.id AND d.name ='IT'
ORDER BY 
    e.salary DESC
```

This is supposed to show me 4 results. Because I'm including the ties. But for some reason it is not. I don't understand why. I need the top 3 salaries including the ties.

I get this result:

| Department | Employee | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IT | Max | 90000 |
| IT | Randy | 85000 |
| IT | Joe | 85000 |

Expected results:

| Department | Employee | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IT | Max | 90000 |
| IT | Randy | 85000 |
| IT | Joe | 85000 |
| IT | Will | 70000 |

Employee table

| Id | Name | Salary | DepartmentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 85000 | 1 |
| 2 | Henry | 80000 | 2 |
| 3 | Sam | 60000 | 2 |
| 4 | Max | 90000 | 1 |
| 5 | Janet | 69000 | 1 |
| 6 | Randy | 85000 | 1 |
| 7 | Will | 70000 | 1 |

Department table:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IT |
| 2 | Sales |

Comment: What is the datataype of `salary`? And why are you using old style `,` joins?

Comment: 85000 is what you see, but it's likely not exactly that so it's not an exact tie is my first guess.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need window functions for this.  `SELECT TOP (n) WITH TIES` stops at row `n` and only includes more rows if there are ties.

So, in addition to proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax, you can learn about window functions:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT d.name as department, e.name as employee, e.salary,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY e.salary DESC) as seqnum
      FROM employee e JOIN
           department d
           ON e.departmentid = d.id and d.name = 'IT'
     ) e
WHERE seqnum <= 3
ORDER BY e.salary DESC
```